# Count for local notification registration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, notifications

Is there any way I can see how many times my view controller has registered for a local notification? My notification handler method is getting called more than once even if notification is sent just once.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you're not registering the notifications in the past, i.e., anytime before the current time on your device.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

the above code will give you an NSArray of all the scheduled local notifications..

if you want to check `notifications` registered by particular view..you must set a value in a `NSDicationary` and set the dictionary to be notification's `user info` property...(when creating notifications)

then you can get the array(first line of my answer) and then enumerate the notification and check the value for dictionary and count the results

More info here : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

Answer (score 0):

You should check to ensure your view controller is not leaked and you have 2 instances of it running (both would respond to notifications).